# How to Change the grid view item height (First item height is equals to the item 2 and item 3)

Tags: android

I want to have a gridview similar to this

[image]

Comment: Use Staggered Grid View.

Answer (score 0):

Create custom adapter with multiple view holders and then inflate views according to your design, following link might be more helpful https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView

Answer (score 0):

Try This

http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/learn-recyclerview-with-an-example-in-android

Hope you are looking for this

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet:

```
<GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:useDefaultMargins="true"
        >

        <Button
            android:layout_rowSpan="2"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="0.5"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:text="Button 1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="0.5"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:text="Button 2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:text="Button 3" />


        <Button
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:text="Button 4" />

        <Button
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:text="Button 5" />
        <Button
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_rowSpan="2"
            android:text="Button 6" />

        <Button
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_rowSpan="2"
            android:text="Button 7" />
        <Button
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:text="Button 8" />
        <Button
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:text="Button 9" />

    </GridLayout>
```

[image]